# Referencing non-static method in a static way

Tags: c#, .net, static-methods

I have this C# class:

```
public static class HealthCheckHighMark
{

    public static IEndpointConventionBuilder MapHighMarkChecks(
        this IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints)
    {

        return endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/api/health/highmark", new HealthCheckOptions
        {
            ResponseWriter = async (context, report) =>
            {
                var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
                    new HighMarkResult
                    {
                        HighMark = HHandler.GetHighMark().High.ToString(),
                    }, Formatting.None,
                    new JsonSerializerSettings
                    {
                        NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
                    });
                context.Response.ContentType = MediaTypeNames.Application.Json;
                await context.Response.WriteAsync(result);
            },

            Predicate = (check) => check.Tags.Contains("highmark")
        });
    }
}
```

`HHandler.GetHighMark()` is a non-static method in the `HHandler` class:

```
public WatermarkOffsets GetHighMark()
{
    return consumer.QueryWatermarkOffsets(TopicPartition.TopicPartition, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
}
```

When I run my check I get a `HTTP 500` error with the following error in the log:

> 2021-03-03 11:54:51.308Z ERROR APP=2227 COMP=3789 [13] Connection id "0HM6U7CJEMU0S", Request id "0HM6U7CJEMU0S:00000001": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application. - Logger=Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel,Level=ERROR,ThreadId=13,,Exception="System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Confluent.Kafka.WatermarkOffsets Ed.Md.FHandler.Health.HHandler.GetHighMark()'.
> at Ed.Health.HealthCheckHMark.<>c.<<-cctor>b__2_0>d.MoveNext()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
> at Ed.Health.HealthCheckHMark.<>c.<.cctor>b__2_0(HttpContext context, HealthReport report)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks.HealthCheckMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)"

I think the issue is that I'm trying to reference a non-static method in a static way. How do I resolve this though?

**Additional Info**

Here's my `HHandler` class:

```
public class HHandler : IHHandler
{
    private readonly IConfig _config;
    public IConsumer<Ignore, MdpMessage> consumer { get;  set; }
    public TopicPartitionOffset TopicPartition { get; set; }

    public HHandler([NotNull] IConfig healthOptions)
    {
        _config = healthOptions;
    }

    public WatermarkOffsets GetHighMark()
    {
        return consumer.QueryWatermarkOffsets(TopicPartition.TopicPartition, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
    }

    WatermarkOffsets IHHandler.GetHighMark()
    {
        return GetHighMark();
    }
}
```

Comment: Create an instance of `HHandler` class and then invoke the method using that instance.

Comment: `HighMark = (h) => h.GetHighMark().High.ToString()` maybe?

Comment: Your code would not compile, because you cant call a non-static method without an instance of the class. How could you run it?

Comment: If "GetHighMark()" is a non static method then "HHandler.GetHighMark()" should not even comile.

Comment: Can you show HHandler class pls?

Comment: HHandler added to question.

Comment: This code **cannot** compile. Question should be closed as not reproducible.

Comment: Sorry, you're correct. This doesn't work but it's where I'm currently at after looking at it for some time. I get that I'm trying to access a non-static method from a static class. To do this I'd usually inject an instance of HHandler into my constructor and reference the instance of  `HHandler` instead of `HHandler.GetHighMark` but that won't work with a static class. Not really sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to check in this healthcheck endpoint?

It is ussialy used to check that some existing system is healthy, like internal DB connection is ok, or some resources are below limits etc.
So you need to run a check on *that* existing system - if it's not a sttatic class, than there should be an instance somewhere, singleton maybe, or some way to create that instance (some factory for example), if it's transient. Usialy a good idea is to ask a DI container to resolve the instance for you. Providing that you are using DI of course (well, in a modern AspNetCore I think you should use it :)

Try something like

```
context.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(HHandler)).GetHighMark().High.ToString()
```

and see if this helps.